# Get difference of proto buffer files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there any options to get difference between two protobufs using C++ and protobuf API? For example: 
I have two files 
**1.txt**

```
Config {
    OtherField:   42
    GoodField:    13
    AnotherField: 4200
}
```

**2.txt**

```
Config {
    OtherField:  19
    GoodField:   13
}
```

I want to get output like:

```bash
Diff:
OtherField   - 1.txt: 42
             - 2.txt: 19
AnotherField - 1.txt: 4200
             - 2.txt: missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`google::protobuf::util::MessageDifferencer`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/). Because there's no single definition for the "difference" between two proto messages, `MessageDifferencer` comes with a number of ways to customize the comparison, including

- Ignoring specific fields with [`IgnoreField`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.IgnoreField) (maybe your message contains a globally unique ID that you don't want to compare)
- Ignoring repeated field ordering with [`TreatAsSet`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.TreatAsSet.details) - but note that set-like comparison is quadratic in the number of elements!
- [`EQUIVALENT`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.MessageFieldComparison.details) comparison for treating unset fields as though they were set to their default value

Once you've configured the `MessageDifferencer`, use [`ReportDifferencesTo`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.ReportDifferencesTo.details) or [`ReportDifferencesToString`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.ReportDifferencesToString.details) to specify how you want to handle the conflicts between the messages, and finally call [`Compare`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.Compare.details) to do the actual work of differencing.

Comment: I have a question - is it possible to report only about fields changed and no information about values changed? For example, I have such output:
"modified: sub.field1: 20 -> 200;
added: struct_field: { field1: "hello" }"

But I want such:
"modified: sub.field1;
added: struct_field.field1"

Comment: I've made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067584/get-difference-of-proto-buffer-files-without-changed-values

Comment: @wowonline I assume you used `ReportDifferencesToString`? Instead, you can implement a custom [`Reporter`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.Reporter) and pass it into [`ReportDifferencesTo`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer/#MessageDifferencer.ReportDifferencesTo.details); this will let you handle the individual field conflicts however you want to.